# How to properly override User admin in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to add add inline model and exclude some fields from User change form in Django admin.

I'm trying to override Django's built-in `UserAdmin` to preserve User change design:

```
class UserCustomAdmin(UserAdmin):
    # list_display = ['id', 'username','email', 'last_login']
    exclude = ['groups','user_permissions']
    inlines = [UserProfileInline]
```

Even `exclude = ['groups']` raises error:

> u"Key 'groups' not found in 'UserForm'. Choices are: date_joined,
>   email, first_name, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login,
>   last_name, password, username."

How to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groups` field appears in the [`UserAdmin.fieldsets`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L45) also.
The error appears, I think, because you exclude the field from form, but later is defined in the fieldsets and form fails.

Try to overwrite the `fieldsets` accordingly, in your `UserCustomAdmin` with no `groups` field.