# Django Admin - call change_view for inline

Tags: django, django-admin

I am currently developing an application in Django.

**In the Admin part, I would like to exclude the "groups" part in the modification view, using the "change_view" method**

Here is the error returned:

[image: [IMAGE ERROR]]

Information: I have an extended user table. In addition the error indicates that I can try with "user_permissions", but after testing it tells me again that I can use "groups" ... So it's not a naming problem

Here is the code:

```
# ADMIN #
class UserExtendInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserExtend
    max_num = 1
    fk_name = 'user'
    can_delete = False
    fields = ('user','offer', 'valid_payments')


class AccountsUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserExtendInline,)
    list_display = ('email','first_name','last_name','Formation_Souscrite','last_login','Paiement_Valide','is_active')
    readonly_fields = ('email', 'last_login', 'date_joined')
    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(AccountsUserAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)

    def Formation_Souscrite(self, obj):
        user_extend =  UserExtend.objects.filter(user=obj).prefetch_related('offer')
        user_extend = user_extend[0]
        if not user_extend.offer is None:
            return user_extend.offer.name
        else:
            return "Aucune"

    def Paiement_Valide(self, obj):
        return UserExtend.objects.get(user=obj).valid_payments

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):       
        self.exclude = ['groups']
        return super(AccountsUserAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, extra_context)

    Paiement_Valide.boolean = True

# unregister old user admin
admin.site.unregister(User)

# register new user admin that includes a UserProfile
admin.site.register(User, AccountsUserAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

Thank you for your reply

**EDIT**

The UserExtend model :

```
class UserExtend(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False,null=False)
    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer, on_delete=models.PROTECT,null=True)
    valid_payments = models.BooleanField(default=False,verbose_name="Paiement Valide")
    stripe_id=models.CharField(max_length=150,default="",verbose_name="Stripe ID Client")
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Extension d'un Utilisateur"
        verbose_name_plural = "Extensions des Utilisateurs"
```

Comment: Could you post the UserExtend code from models.py

Comment: it's posted, thank you for your help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly override User admin in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934609/how-to-properly-override-user-admin-in-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is duplicate of [How to properly override User admin in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934609/how-to-properly-override-user-admin-in-django)

So, you should override the fieldsets without the 'groups'. The original fieldsets definition is here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/0352a44dd61c19bebf0c0b305dbbc3f710ff9945/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L48

Just omit the 'groups' in the overridden definition.

Comment: It's perfect, Simple and efficient, thank you so much !